# Problem with gesture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, gesture

I tried this code ......

```
self.swipeRecognizer = [UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:);
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer;
```

It works fine in the simulator, but while working with the device I get the following error:

```
2011-02-25 11:16:25.250 OnlyGizmos489:207 *** -UISwipeGestureRecognizer setDirection:: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b6950
2011-02-25 11:16:25.257 OnlyGizmos489:207 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -UISwipeGestureRecognizer setDirection:: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b6950'
2011-02-25 11:16:25.269 OnlyGizmos489:207 Stack: (
843263261,
825818644,
843267069,
842763033,
842725440,
26283,
844154820,
844283872,
844283288,
844282948,
844281236,
844280752,
844182692,
844181896,
21373,
844473760,
844851728,
862896011,
843011267,
843009055,
860901832,
843738160,
843731504,
11617,
11532
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal: “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On which device are you trying to run this project as UIGestureRecognizer is available from iOS 3.2 and above.

Comment: no wonder your application is crashing... I have already mention the minimum requirement for UIGestureRecognizer is iOS 3.2